# Multiple css file with one http request

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm new to Web development so sorry if this question may seem obvious.

I would like to separate my css files in precise categories.

- buttons.css
- lists.css
- reset.css

But I know that doing so, and importing them with pure css, will cause multiple http requests, slowing down the page loading.

I know that something is possible with a  language called Sass. Thing is, I would like to avoid it, and try to fix this using only css standard.

Is it even possible? Or sass and other things like it are the only solution?

Thanks!

Comment: May be you could keep an nodejs server, which reads all 3 css files, and combine them together to create style.css and send it as one file.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this with plain CSS.

- If you want to fetch all the CSS with one HTTP request, then all the CSS needs to be in one file.
- If you want to write your CSS in separate files, then they won't be.

You can use a tool which will combine those files into a single file. SASS is one such tool (and one which is very popular, well tested, and abundant in other features). You can write a single  file which `@imports` the CSS files (which, IIRC, will requires `.scss` file extensions) and otherwise not use any SASS features at all.

You could use other tools instead (such as `cat`).

Comment: You could solve that with [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/guide-http2-server-push/) as well: client requests button.css, you send lists.css and reset.css as well. But some build step `cat *.css > bundle.css` is the more common option, I think.

Comment: So Sass is the only way you can archive that. I mean sass and other tools like it. Very sad.

Comment: @RavenMask — Text files are not magic. They can't simultaneously be split up and together. It's a fundamental feature of how the universe works.